# paygate payweb3 integration in php website

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate `paygate payment gateway` integration into my `PHP API`. I have gone through their documentation but it is not clear for me. There were three endpoints

1. initiate
2. return
3. query

I don't which endpoint to use. Now I am using initiate endpoint, but when testing in postman I am getting an error

> ERROR=DATA_CHK error

Can anyone guide me to sort this out...

```
public function subscription(Request $request) {   
        $validator = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            array(
                 'subscription' => 'required|integer',
                 'email' => 'required|exists:users,email',
                 'amount' => 'required|integer',
                 'payment_mode' => 'required|integer',
            ),
            array(
                'exists' => 'The :attribute doesn\'t exists',
            )
        );

        if ($validator->fails()) {

            $error_messages = implode(',', $validator->messages()->all());

            $response_array = array('success' => false, 'error' => Helper::get_error_message(101), 'error_code' => 101, 'error_messages'=>$error_messages);

        } else {
                
                $encryptionKey = 'AQ2Uted8BidhkIEv6oYgrqwS'; 

                $data = array(
                    'PAYGATE_ID'        => 1039433100014,
                    'REFERENCE'         => 'pgtest_123456789',
                    'AMOUNT'            => 3299,
                    'CURRENCY'          => 'ZAR',
                    'RETURN_URL'        => 'http://localhost/avvata/public/home',
                    'TRANSACTION_DATE'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'LOCALE'            => 'en-za',
                    'COUNTRY'           => 'ZAF',
                    'EMAIL'             => $request->email,
                );

                $checksum = md5(implode('', $data) . $encryptionKey);

                $data['CHECKSUM'] = $checksum;

                $fieldsString = http_build_query($data);

                //open connection
                $ch = curl_init();

                //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://secure.paygate.co.za/payweb3/initiate.trans');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldsString);

                //execute post
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                 echo  $result;
                 exit();
                //close connection
                curl_close($ch); 
}`
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Late to the party here, but PayGate does not allow calls from and returns to localhost.